# Require maths help calculating deflection angles of quadrants

Tags: trigonometry

For each quadrant, I need to find a neat way of calculating the deflection angle for a small circular object striking a circle, as shown in the diagram.

[image: Quadrants for Defection]

- Angles a and b are already known.
- Angle a is always relative to 0 degrees position.
- Angle b is relative to the quadrant.
- The initial angle can also be greater than 180, when coming from the
  other direction, as shown in the diagram the right.

For quadrant 2, in the following snippet from my code, dy and dx represent the x and y coordinates of a point on the circle:

```
intersectAngle = atan(dy/dx);
```

Initial angle is calculated from velocity vectors:

```
pAngle = PI - (atan2(pVel.x, pVel.y));
```

For quadrant 0, I came up with this for the rebound angle:

```
pAngle = pAngle - 2 *(pAngle - tangentAngle);
```

Where tangentAngel is just the intersect angle with half PI added. Thsi worked for a ball from any direction.

Moving onto quadrant 1, this works for pAngles of less than 90 deg, but not for pAngles from the other direction:

```
pAngle = pAngle + 0.5 * PI - intersectAngle;
```

Feels like I shouldn't be writing all this code and that there is a more efficient way. I realise this is an elementary question but I'm studying this so it's all new to me. Please be gentle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like you are just reflecting the vector and it would be easier to do so, as such, than manually fiddle with quadrant math. I think you have access to vectors but, if it's a project constraint, I can modify this to use only basic scientific calculator functions. `V1` relates to angle `a` and `V2` relates to angle `b`. All vectors should be normalized.

This works for any vector, in any quadrant:

[image]

1. I believe `V1` is `pVel`, normalized.
2. I believe `V2` is `{dx, dy}`, normalized.
3. `V3.Dot(V2) == -V1.Dot(V2)`
4. The angle between `V3` and `V2` is `acos(-V1.Dot(V2))`
5. The angle between `V3` and '0' is `acos(-V1.Dot(V2)) + b`
6. Post-collision velocity is `V3` * the original magnitude of `V1`

This could happen if you detect the wrong collision first (very little implementation detail included):

[image]

Leave a comment if you need help with it.

Comment: Thanks, and yes, I am reflecting the vector. Could you clarify what you mean by "normalised"?

Comment: @Jason210, the entirety of trig happens on the unit-circle (radius 1, shown dashed in white). For example, to normalize the vector `{10, 0}` (solid green + purple), you divide by it's length, 10, to get `{1, 0}` (dashed green), a unit-vector pointing in the same direction.

Comment: @Jason210, before normalizing, `V1` includes the purple extension beyond the unit-circle; after normalizing it becomes unit-length (solid green), but we shift it to `X0` (dashed green). Also, `.Dot()` refers to the dot-product and is the red leg of the dashed triangle. `V1.Dot(V2)` is the "magnitude of `V1` in the `V2` direction" and will range from -1 to +1 if all inputs are normalized.

Comment: Thanks. There are some new and valuable concepts for me here. I'm going to try to implement your suggestion...

Comment: @Jason210, I notice `pVel` has x and y components, so if that's an actual vector class, it's probably got built-in methods for all of this (possibly even `.Reflect()`); you weren't specific about language or development environment. I'm going to step-by-step the first diagram tomorrow and can add code if you get stuck.

Comment: This question was an abstraction of a problem of a ball colliding on the corners of a box. Do you think you could help me with that if I ask it as a new question?

Comment: Development environment is Processing.

Comment: @Jason210, I'd be happy to; post a link to it here so I get notified.

Comment: @Jason210 just a thought but you might find this book is helpful - http://www.amazon.com/Math-Primer-Graphics-Development-Edition/dp/1568817231

Comment: Thanks. I had to finish my assignment and get it handed it in...using my cumbersome trigonometry. At least it worked - but I'm definitely going to look into using dot product to modify vectors in future.

Comment: @Jason210, you can easily adapt this method for cube collisions by replacing `V2` with the collided cube-face's normal. Also, you might as well learn cross-product too, while you're at it. The cross-product of two vectors is a third vector that is perpendicular to both inputs and is the normal of the plane that contains both inputs.